# Video Calling from saturn

Tags: time-dilation

It's only a hypothetical example.-

What will be the time dilatation effect in the following cases. Suppose the video length is 1 hour(with earth) then how long is the duration of these videos on saturn-

Playing a youtube video on saturn that was made on earth

Playing a youtube that was made and played on saturn

Live video calling a person from saturn to earth.

Comment: *What will be the time dilatation effect* Too small to notice.

Comment: Do you mean because time travels slower in strong gravity like on Saturn? Or time travels slower because Saturn is moving with respect to Earth? Are you interested in Saturn in particular? Or do you just want to know what happens in strong gravity and/or high speed?

Comment: I meant time travels slower in strong gravity like on Saturn.

Comment: @G.Smith What should be the minimum length of the video so that time dilation comes to play?

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/478481/is-there-a-temporal-difference-between-planets-due-to-the-suns-gravitational-fi/478613) for time dilation calculations on each planet.